# What does the Bible say about giving your life away for Jesus?

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, biblical-basis, exegesis

On a Christian radio station I constantly hear the phrase "to give your life away for Jesus" but they never say what that means.

I am very confused about this concept. Any clarification is helpful, thanks !

Comment: When you say: "Life" what do you mean by that?  Do you mean your money?  Money and life are almost exchangable (money buys anything under the sun) which is the enabler of life.  So rephrasing the question, what does the bible say about giving your money away for Jesus.  The answer is clear, 10% of before tax earnings.

Comment: "He who has found his life will lose it, and he who has lost his life for My sake will find it." (Matt. 10:39) "and He died for all, so that they who live might no longer live for themselves, but for Him who died and rose again on their behalf." (2 Cor. 5:15) "I have been crucified with Christ; and it is no longer I who live, but Christ lives in me; and the life which I now live in the flesh I live by faith in the Son of God, who loved me and gave Himself up for me." (Gal. 2:20)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, and I would be curious as to what verses they were referring to (if any) so I could better answer the question, but I'll take a quick whack at it.

Things were perfect in the garden of Eden. Jesus was the ruler and there was no sin. When Adam and Eve chose to partake of the fruit of knowledge of good and evil, they brought sin into the world. Therefore, they lost direct connection to Jesus.

When Jesus died on the cross He once again opened the gateway to God through Jesus (this is the significance of the veil tearing, but that is different story).

God was in control when man was perfect, we gave up that control to ourselves. Jesus knew we couldn't do it on our own so He sent the Holy Spirit to instruct us. The Holy Spirit can't control what happens on the earth unless we, humans, allow it. Jesus will never come against free will. Satan doesn't have that power either, all he can do is trick us into believe wrong things. It is our choice and will always be our choice.

When someone "gives up their life for Jesus", they are asking for Jesus to come and take control of their lives. They are giving up their right to accomplish things on their own strength. Once this surrender happens, Jesus can work in ways unimaginable.

```
"I can do all things through Christ who strengthens me" - Phil 4:13
```

To taste that strength, you have to be willing to give up your free will and to give it to Jesus.

Comment: I am sorry it is vague, but it really is a big question mark to me. You quote here gives me some insight "giving up their right to accomplish things on their own strength". However "you have to be willing to give up your free will and to give it to Jesus" - how would Jesus then make decisions for us? If I just give up my free will other men will fill it with their will....please explain. thank you.

Comment: That was unclear sorry, whenever I say "giving up" I am meaning to give it over to Christ. Jesus knows when we ask Him to personally take control.

Comment: Phil, how do you describe the things He can take control of vs. the things we have to do for ourselves? I don't know when to be passive and let go or when to help myself...or is it a mix of these, very confused! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

and a good question:

As far as I can find, Jesus never said this, however, He did say, "Follow Me."

As you read the Gospels, Jesus makes clear that it is He who lays down His life, shedding His blood, the purpose?  So that those who believe in Him can receive the gift of eternal life.

To believe, in the times of Jesus, what he meant, is exactly what He means today.  To believe in something and not do anything about it, means you actually don't believe according to the teaching of Jesus.  As John the Baptist put it, your life and the way you now live is the proof you have repented.  Repent means to recognize a truth by applying it to your life and the way you live. If you believe the plane does not have enough fuel to get across the Atlantic, do you get on knowing it will crash in the sea? No you don't, you will find the pilot would refuse to fly such a plane with such knowledge.

Knowing who Jesus is, The Son of God who by His death takes away the sin of the world, you need to decide what you are going to do about it. Accept it and do nothing? or Accept it and do what He said those who believe in Him must to keep your life at His coming! Strong words!

Consider Matthew Chapters 5, 6 & 7, at the end Jesus points out that those who carried out His teaching are "wise builders" those who don't are not. Those who don't do what He said, He will say; "I never knew you; depart from me, you that work iniquity." Jesus is referring to the unwise builders who built there life on sand.

To be a Christian is actually to be a disciple of Jesus, one who follows His example, He obeyed His Father, disciples follow Jesus in the same way by obeying the teaching of Jesus and applying such to their life.  Jesus pointed out, if you want to follow Him you need to "deny yourself, take up your cross and follow Me", to be an obedient disciple of Jesus means saying no to your desires if they ever come into conflict with His teaching and put His teaching first, taking up your cross is the walk of denying what you want in such circumstances and go on to follow His example which He laid down, He obeyed His Father above all else, we are to obey what Jesus taught above all else.

If you consider yourself to be a christian and have not lived this way, His way, then it is time to consider if you are prepared to pay the price. There is the opportunity to repent offered to those who recognize and accept the truth about Jesus but have lived a life in opposition to His doctrine, His teachings, read Revelation Chapters 2 and 3.

The 7 Churches in Revelation are an example of believers who Jesus points out they are living in disobedience, or at least 5 of them are.  Jesus tells them to repent, to change the way they are living, the way they are thinking about Him.

The above in today's world appears to be unpalatable and some think unreasonable in today's modern society, do you not consider, in the day that Jesus lived, it was not radical, challenging and very unpalatable, however, Jesus said, "repent for the Kingdom of Heaven is at hand." In that day, some felt it worth it, to receive the gift of complete forgiveness for their sins and follow Jesus so as to keep the gift of eternal life.

Let me put it this way; By repenting and believing in Jesus, you begin to change the way you think about everything, at the same time, by the presence of The Holy Spirit, you are sanctified.  God provides you with wedding garments, clean and white so that you can go to the wedding of His Son Jesus.  Your job now is to keep your wedding garments clean. You change the way you live by living how Jesus said live, He also gave tips on how to walk, 'do unto others how you want them to do to you', so you, forgiven by Him forgive others.  So your walk of following Jesus begins, if you trip and fall, get up, clean off the dirt and repair your wedding garments by repenting, recognizing your error and saying sorry, then move on, this time on your guard not to make that mistake again.

This is the life of a disciple of Jesus, walking each day, one day at a time, keeping your eyes on Jesus and pondering His words in your heart, living a life of daily 'Asking Him', 'Seeking Him', 'Knocking on His door', and knowing, when you ask, according to His teaching, He answers your requests, your daily walk of getting to know Jesus and His Father better day by day.  Storms will come, hardship will come, the walk is not easy, but, the reward, when you stand before Him, the garments you were given, gleaming white, because you looked after what He paid the price to give you, what an amazing experience that will be!

You don't stand before Him in your righteousness but in His gift of righteousness, however, He will reward you for valuing and caring for the wonderful gift He gave you to look after by the way you think and live here on this world as a follower of Jesus!

That is my interpretation of 'giving your life to Jesus', when in fact it was His life He gave for YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Well as giving your life to i personnel believe we as Christians or human beings we have gone short f God's glory we cant stand in his sight why we are dirt. he can't look at us. So as for that matter Jesus died so that he can restore our original image to God. How ever this need Faith we by you do things because you believe that he s there and infect they is nothing he can not do for you and me as far as he die so he dose all we are in need off. First and for all we need to understand what faith means to us it consist of trust, hope and belief. Faith is the assurance of things hoped for and also trust in his promises in absence of solidification of their presence

Give you life and all you have to Jesus its a sign of saying i trust in the as he said keep all you treasurers in heaven where no thief can break in and steel, you only do this with faith knowing that for all your needs he will provide.

The problems we have as Christians is that we take things and matters into our on imagination and by doing so we are not giving Jesus his roll to make things possible by all means

Jesus can decide for your in everything only if you give him the room to do so.

We have a problem of take God's matter into physical action or feeling which is wrong faith does not feel or appear to be physical you can not give its characteristic its only in the spirit as we are of the spirit living in the physical body as Christ did

Be like Christ as he walk in this sinful world.

Comment: I don't disagree with what you say, but this would be a far better answer if you cited Scripture, particularly since the question specifically asks "what does the Bible say".